# Filter list items by class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, filtering

I am modifying an existing website's A-Z directory, it is a filtered list using jQuery. Clicking on **ALL** shows all departments. Each section A-Z are grouped inside their own div with a matching class, for example all departments starting with **A** have a div with a class "A".

I need to filter out an additional group of items in the list in the same manner, when clicking on **GILROY**. I have added the class "gilroy" to these list items.

After spending several hours trying to decipher similar examples using filtering I realize I just don't understand how to properly code it, and it is a time sensitive project. Any assistance or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

The existing code that I am modifying is below, see jsfiddle link for css & html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#letterlist a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#letterlist .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toUpperCase().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'ALL') {
            $('div#departments div').addClass('column');
            $('div#departments div div.hidden').fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('div#departments div.column').fadeIn('fast').removeClass('column');

            $('div#departments div div').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('fast').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        } 

        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaemak/RSpP9/1/)

Comment: This code will never work for the sub-search you want, simply because the class of `gilroy` is on a `list item` and you're never even filtering against list items...

Comment: If you're going to link a jsfiddle in your question, it should be a fork or something.  You're making changes to it that, for example, invalidate my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ach, edited link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another case to your `if-then-else` for `GILROY`.  In this case, show everything, just like the `ALL` case, but hide all but the `.gilroy` class `li` elements, using `.not('.gilroy')`.  Make sure to `show()` all of the `li` elements on each change to reset the filter:

```
$('div#departments li').show();
if(filterVal == 'GILROY') {
    $('div#departments div').addClass('column');
    $('div#departments li').not('.gilroy').hide();
    $('div#departments div div.hidden').fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hidden');
} else if(filterVal == 'ALL') {
    $('div#departments div').addClass('column');
    $('div#departments div div.hidden').fadeIn('fast').removeClass('hidden');
} else {
    ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8u26c/

Comment: Thank you! This works great, however I need to hide any h5 that does not have the class name "gilroy" on a list item inside that particular div. Example: `<div class="B"><h5>B</h5>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="behavioral-medicine.html">Behavioral Medicine</a></li>
              
            <li><a href="business-strategy-finance.html">Business Strategy &amp; Finance</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>`

Comment: I had a feeling you might need that.  I made an example of that here: http://jsfiddle.net/66eSB/  I had the script add a class `nogilroy` to each group without a `li.gilroy` at load time.  (Actually added it to all and then removed it from any group with a `li.gilroy`)  Then I just hide the `.nogilroy` groups as part of the filter.  There are a number of other ways you could do it as well, including rearranging your HTML a bit.  This is one way.

Comment: Here is a slightly better version with comments: http://jsfiddle.net/66eSB/1/  It deals with some animation issues when a user clicks too fast.

Comment: Wonderful! I have learned more by looking at your modifications next to what I started with, than I did while researching on my own. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

This one should work with "Gilroy" and any other similar filters you might decide to add.  You can have an empty `div` with class `GILROY` and an empty `ul` (which seemed to already exist in an earlier version of your jsfiddle), and then add the following snippet in your `else` block:

```
if (filterVal.length > 1) { //can hard-code this to check for "GILROY" instead, if you want
    var targetList = $('div.' + filterVal + ' ul');
    $('li.' + filterVal.toLowerCase()).each(function() {
        targetList.append($(this));
    });                
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/82Vmw/